# Starting up several programs at once

Tags: c#

I have written a small program (ProcessSample) to launch another programs that are defined in the .txt file (separated by new line).

The code is mostly taken from MSDN. I am just starting my programming adventure but I want to write something useful.

I don't know the smart way to run for example two programs simultaneously from my ProcessSample program.

In my .txt file I have just paths to programs with .exe. It's all working fine but my program is only running one program at the time. I thought I would run foreach but of course it won't work here as it just runs the first program and it waits till I exit it, then it will run the next one.

So I know the reason why is it not working. I just want to know how could I make it work the way I would like.

My C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProcessSample
{
    class ProcessMonitorSample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.BufferHeight = 25;

            // Define variables to track the peak memory usage of the process. 
            long peakWorkingSet = 0;

            string[] Programs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Programs\list.txt");

            foreach (string Program in Programs)
            {
                Process myProcess = null;

                // Start the process.
                myProcess = Process.Start(@Program);

                // Display the process statistics until 
                // the user closes the program. 
                do
                {
                    if (!myProcess.HasExited)
                    {
                        // Refresh the current process property values.
                        myProcess.Refresh();

                        // Display current process statistics.
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}, RAM: {1}", Program, (myProcess.WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024));

                        // Update the values for the overall peak memory statistics.
                        peakWorkingSet = myProcess.PeakWorkingSet64;

                        if (myProcess.Responding)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Status: Running");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Status: Not Responding!");
                        }

                        // Wait 2 seconds
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    } // if
                } // do
                while (!myProcess.WaitForExit(1000));

                Console.WriteLine(); 
                Console.WriteLine("Process exit code: {0}", myProcess.ExitCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Peak physical memory usage of the process: {0}", (peakWorkingSet / 1024 / 1024));

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
                System.Console.ReadKey();
           } // foreach
        } // public
    } //class
} // namespace
```

Comment: You're explicitly checking if the program has finished its execution: "if (!myProcess.HasExited)" and "while (!myProcess.WaitForExit(1000));"

Comment: The reason it isn't working as you would expect is because you enter the loop, start the program and wait for the program to end before starting the next loop. You should move the Process monitoring outside of the loop and possibly onto a a different Thread so that all the programs may be started at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have learned about Threads and I have used them for my program like this:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] myApps = { "notepad.exe", "calc.exe", "explorer.exe" };

    Thread w;
    ParameterizedThreadStart ts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartMyApp);
    foreach (var myApp in myApps)
    {
        w = new Thread(ts);
        w.Start(myApp);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private static void StartMyApp(object myAppPath)
{
    ProcessStartInfo myInfoProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
    myInfoProcess.FileName = myAppPath.ToString();
    myInfoProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    Process myProcess = Process.Start(myInfoProcess);

    do
    {
        if (!myProcess.HasExited)
        {
            myProcess.Refresh(); // Refresh the current process property values.
            Console.WriteLine(myProcess.ProcessName+" RAM: "+(myProcess.WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024).ToString()+"\n");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    while (!myProcess.WaitForExit(1000)); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the inner while loop. There you are getting statistics from the running process and displaying them in the console. As far as I understand from your post, you don't need this feature so you can remove it and you would get:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProcessSample
{
    class ProcessMonitorSample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.BufferHeight = 25;

            // Define variables to track the peak memory usage of the process. 
            long peakWorkingSet = 0;

            string[] Programs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Programs\list.txt");

            foreach (string Program in Programs)
            {
                Process myProcess = null;

                // Start the process.
                myProcess = Process.Start(@Program);

                Console.WriteLine("Program started: {0}", Program);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that but I want to know for example "Peak physical memory usage of the process" when I am going to close the program that I have started up.  I also want it to refresh every 2 seconds with information on RAM usage, the same way I have written my program. I would like my program to be providing the same information but with ability to run simultaneously many programs at the same time.

Comment: Ok, than the easiest way would be to replace the for each with the parallel for each as described in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your foreach with Parallel.ForEach to achieve what you want.

```
 Parallel.ForEach<String>(Programs, Program =>
            {
                Process myProcess = null;

                // Start the process.
                myProcess = Process.Start(@Program);

                // Display the process statistics until 
                // the user closes the program. 
                do
                {
                    if (!myProcess.HasExited)
                    {
                        // Refresh the current process property values.
                        myProcess.Refresh();

                        // Display current process statistics.

                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}, RAM: {1}", Program, (myProcess.WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024));

                        // Update the values for the overall peak memory statistics.
                        peakWorkingSet = myProcess.PeakWorkingSet64;

                        if (myProcess.Responding)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Status: Running");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Status: Not Responding!");
                        }

                        // Wait 2 seconds
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                }
                while (!myProcess.WaitForExit(1000));

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Process exit code: {0}", myProcess.ExitCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Peak physical memory usage of the process: {0}", (peakWorkingSet / 1024 / 1024));

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
                System.Console.ReadKey();
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working awesome so far. I believe that is what I was looking for!